How to Retrieve Order Sales Channel Details (Origin, Referrer, Landing Site) Using Adobe Commerce/Magento API?
I am importing the orders from our client's Adobe Commerce (Magento) store using API. I I need to retrieve sales channel details for orders. Specifically, I need to access information such as:

The origin of the order (e.g., UTM source or medium, google, bing)
The referring site (e.g., the HTTP referrer)
The landing page where the customer started their session

What I've Tried:

I explored the GET rest/V1/orders endpoint and rest/V1/products/{id} of the Magento REST API, but I couldn't find explicit fields for this data.
I reviewed the API responses but couldn't find any data related to the order sales channel.

How can I retrieve this information using the Magento REST API or any other way via API?
Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
